# Passenger keep-alive? (Disable passenger's auto shutdown)

Tags: passenger

I'm building a service which integrates within slack slash commands. Through the night, passenger automatically shuts down my rails application.
So the next day, the first request will result in a timeout, because passenger is still booting my app.

Is there any way to always keep the application running?

Note: I'm using `mod_passenger` not passenger standalone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either set a minimum number of instances to keep around with [PassengerMinInstances](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengermininstances) or disable idle shutdown all together with [PassengerPoolIdleTime](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerpoolidletime)